# Background-image will/won't cover whole window, depending on server

Tags: html, css

I have a background image covering the whole browser window, and resizing with it (so there is no constant aspect ratio). It is created in css, quite standard, like this:

```
html { 
  background: url(/bgpic.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
      -o-background-size: cover;
         background-size: cover;
}
```

This works perfectly well when run locally. When run from my provider's server, however, the image will only cover approximately the top 2/3 of the window - in any browser.
That is, the picture does have the right size to cover the window, but the bottom third of the window is covered by a band in the background color. (seems I can´t attach screenshots here, sorry).

What's wrong, and more importantly: how can I solve the problem?

Comment: It sounds like you forgot to upload your CSS file to the server

Comment: Do you have a link we can look at?

Comment: I notice you're missing a hyphen preceding the webkit-background-size. Not sure if that would make any difference on a live server over local...

Comment: Can you let us know what OS the server is running and what OS you are using locally? Also if you know what web server software (apache, IIS, etc.).
One other question, have you tried different browsers and are getting the same result?

Comment: Thanks all for your input. I'll clarify: 1.i did upload the css. Here are three links to a test file: 1. at hosting provider lunarpages, California: peptalks.nl/test5.jsp 2. at hosting provider xs4all, Netherlands: www.xs4all.nl/~riksmits/test5,html 3. mockup of correct (local) effect: peptalks.nl/test5ok.html (look at bottom!) All should be like the local mockup, but they aren't. Check the code.